# Failed build openssl 1.0.2p on SLES 12-SP2 x86_64

Tags: linux, openssl, sles

Tried to build openssl 1.0.2p on SLES 12-SP2 x86_64 and it failed
I ran the following commands as standard user:

```
cd /usr/src/openssl-1.0.2p
./config --prefix=/usr/local/ssl --openssldir=/usr/local/ssl shared zlib
make
```

Excerpt from the console

```
make[4]: Entering directory '/usr/src/openssl-1.0.2p'
...
/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.8/../../../../x86_64-suse-linux/bin/ld: libcrypto.a(gost_sign.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata.str1.1' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.8/../../../../x86_64-suse-linux/bin/ld: final link failed: Nonrepresentable section on output
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile.shared:169: recipe for target 'link_a.gnu' failed
make[4]: *** [link_a.gnu] Error 1
make[4]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/openssl-1.0.2p'
Makefile:357: recipe for target 'do_linux-shared' failed
make[3]: *** [do_linux-shared] Error 2
make[3]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/openssl-1.0.2p'
Makefile:310: recipe for target 'libcrypto.so.1.0.0' failed
make[2]: *** [libcrypto.so.1.0.0] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/openssl-1.0.2p'
Makefile:109: recipe for target 'shared' failed
make[1]: *** [shared] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/openssl-1.0.2p/crypto'
Makefile:287: recipe for target 'build_crypto' failed
make: *** [build_crypto] Error 1
tony@linux-31cz:/usr/src/openssl-1.0.2p>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> ./config --prefix=/usr/local/ssl --openssldir=/usr/local/ssl shared zlib
> ```

Followed by...

> ```
> /usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.8/../../../../x86_64-suse-linux/bin/ld:
> libcrypto.a(gost_sign.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against
> `.rodata.str1.1' can not be used when making a shared object;
> recompile with -fPIC
> /usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.8/../../../../x86_64-suse-linux/bin/ld:
> final link failed: Nonrepresentable section on output
> ```

It sounds like you built earlier but omitted `shared`. Then you reconfigured and added `shared`.

You should perform a `make distclean` and then start over. Perform a `distclean`, and then run `./config ...`, `make depends`, `make` and then `make install`.

OpenSSL 1.0.2 requires the `make depends`, so be sure you include the step.

Also see [Compilation and Installation](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Compilation_and_Installation) on the OpenSSL wiki.